# Not working "selected" attribute in "ion-selected" element in ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-forms

I am using ionic 2 for making mobile application. When I use `selected` attribute in `ion-select` element its working for one page but when i am using it for another page(component)its not working .

I am new to Ionic-2

My code for working selected attribute is given below:

```
 <ion-item>
      <ion-label>IO/WBS</ion-label>
        <ion-select interface="popover">
          <ion-option value="Department1" selected>Department 1</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="Department2 ">Department 2</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="Department3 ">Department 3</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Approver</ion-label>
        <ion-select interface="popover">
          <ion-option value="Manager1" selected>Manager 1</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="Manager2 ">Manager 2</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="Manager3 ">Manager 3</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

And my code for non-working "selected" in "ion-select" element is give below:

```
 <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Expense Details</ion-label>
        <ion-select interface="popover" name="check" [(ngModel)]="check" (ionChange)="Change(check)">
          <ion-option value="Bus fare" selected>Bas Fare</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="Train Fare">Train Fare</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="other">Other</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

     <textarea id="box" rows=3 cols=35 style="display:none;text-align:center;" name="description" [(ngModel)]="description" ></textarea>

    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-6>

            <ion-label>Select Currency</ion-label>
                <ion-select interface="popover" name="currency" [(ngModel)]="currency">
                  <ion-option value="INR" selected>INR</ion-option>
                  <ion-option value="GBP ">GBP</ion-option>
                </ion-select>
           </ion-col>
           <ion-col col-6>
              <ion-item>
                 <ion-label floating >Amount</ion-label>
                 <ion-input required  type="number" name="amount" [(ngModel)]="amount"></ion-input >

             </ion-item>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>

  </ion-list>
```

Comment: Show us the .ts file.

Comment: I solved it by my own

Comment: What was the problem? Tell us. Put the answer in your post.

Comment: if you add ngModel then it won’t select any of them unless you set the variable to one of the values in the component. for example                                    

    this.dateExp = "";
   
    this.check = "Bus Fare";
    this.amount = 0;
    this.currency = "INR";
   this.description =""
}

Comment: I thought that might be it, which is why I wanted to see your .ts. Well done. Now add this to the main post.

Comment: But still i am facing same  problem for "Expense Details" field .

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for "Currency filed" by fixing it variable because
if you add ngModel then it won’t select any of them unless you set the variable to one of the values in the component.
 for example :

```
 this.dateExp = "";

    this.check = "Bus fare";
    this.amount = 0;
    this.currency = "INR";
   this.description =""
```

Its working for "INR" but not for Expense details Field .
Anybody suggest me !!!!

Comment: Its Working now  . Do not use value attribute like "Bus fare" , use "Bus_fare"